# Pipes, shell scripts and ulimit

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a command that I'm calling from code:

```
execvp('generate', ...)
```

which is an executable program that my code communicates with via stdin, stdout and stderr. This works fine, not a single problem.

I want to change this so I can set resource limits on `generate`. So I've tried calling:

```
ulimit -t 1 && generate
```

But I get a broken pipe when I try to communicate with it.

So I put the line above in a shell script `generate_wrapper`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -t 1 && generate
```

And I get a broken pipe when I try to communicate with it.

But

```
$ echo "foo" | generate_wrapper
$ echo "foo" | generate
```

both give me the correct, identical output. I figured it might be the &&, so I tried just the bare command:

```
#!/bin/bash
generate
```

But it still works from the CL, and I still get a broken pipe when I try to communicate with it from code.

I tried to explicitly route the fds, and got:

```
#!/bin/bash
generate >&1 2>&2 <&0
```

But no, I still get a broken pipe when I try to communicate with it from code.

So obviously I haven't a clue what I'm doing. Can you help? How do I write a wrapper so I can `ulimit` a spawned subprocess (`rlimit` isn't available for pids in my host language) and still communicate with it?

Comment: I think this should either either get moved to Unix&Linux or StackOverflow since it is about programming and access to Unix resources, not a general computer user question. Don't re-ask, just wait and see. I've flagged it for a moderator to migrate.

Comment: Oh, the broken pipe in all cases is an EPIPE, rather than a SIGPIPE: "Error: EPIPE, Broken pipe"

Comment: Caleb, wasn't sure which way to go, but here did seem to be more questions on piping stuff around bash.

Comment: @lan: That's because new unix users frequently don't understand how the basics of pipes work and on the unix.SE that's kind of assumed knowledge. However your question is a little more advanced than that and involves access from another language and ulimit stuff. That's time for Unix expert advice ... it's more of a programmer question than a usage question.

Comment: pipes, shells scripts and ulimit. O my!

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you don't want to call `ulimit (2)` in the generating code before `execvp`?

From the man page:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>        #include <ulimit.h>
>       long
>        **ulimit** (int cmd, ...);
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>        The ulimit() function will get and set process limits.

Answer (score 1):

`EPIPE` with its "broken pipe" error message is raised when the `SIGPIPE` signal is set to be ignored and a writing process tries to write further output to the already closed reading end of the pipe where, in your case, `generate` has all file descriptors referring to its stdin closed.

If there is a parent process that has set the `SIGPIPE` signal to be ignored, the child process will inherit this behaviour (... and in non-interactive shells this cannot be undone).

So, in your case, the program that calls your `generate` executable has set the `SIGPIPE` signal to be ignored. Then, when your `generate` program in your `generate_wrapper` has processed input for one second (`ulimit -t 1`) `generate` will exit and close its stdin. If your writing process with ignored  `SIGPIPE` then attempts to write further data to the now closed stdin of `generate` the `write` system call will fail and you will see `EPIPE` with its "broken pipe" error message (see `man 2 write`).

As for a wrapper to reduce CPU resource consumption use tools such as [cstream](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html) or [mbuffer](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html).

```
# test: ulimit -t
#help ulimit
{
time -p bash -c 'yes | head -100000000 | wc -c'
echo
time -p bash -c 'ulimit -t 1; yes | head -100000000 | wc -c'
}

# cstream test
#top -u
yes | cstream -b 100000 -t 100000 -o -
yes | cstream -b 100000 -t 100000 | cat -n

# generate_wrapper
#!/bin/bash
cstream -b 100000 -t 100000 | generate
```

Answer (score 0):

execvp does not handle system commands but only direct binaries. Also script files are only masked system commands in this way.

I think you need to use system() if you wish to run commands instead of binaries.

dmckee's idea about calling ulimit() before execvp() is also a sound one. This will however affect everything the process does from here on.

Comment: Unfortunately I neither have rlimit or ulimit available. So the question stands. Can it be done?